# Flashlight with strobe: strobe doesn’t turn OFF

Tags: java, android, button, flashlight

I am trying to create a flashlight app with a strobe effect. My goal is that I can turn ON/OFF the flashlight with a switch Btn and increase the strobe frequency with a seekbar. If the seekbar value is 0 and the switch Btn is ON the flashlight should be ON (without any strobe). But right now it is still blinking (strobe effect ON) if the seekbar value is 0. Do you know how I can change that?
Here is some of the code which I think is important (I really can't find the part which keeps the stobe effect still on:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.mySwitch);

    //listener to check changes in state
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            turnOnOff(isChecked);
        }
    });
    skBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    skBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            freq = progress;
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        cam = Camera.open();
        camParams = cam.getParameters();
        cam.startPreview();
        hasCam = true;
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
private void turnOnOff(boolean on){
    if(on) {
        if(freq != 0){
            sr = new StroboRunner();

            t = new Thread(sr);
            t.start();
            return;
        }else{
            camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        }
    }else if(!on){
        if(t != null){
            sr.stopRunning = true;
            t =null;
            return;
        }else{
            camParams.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
    }
    cam.setParameters(camParams);
    cam.startPreview();
}
private class StroboRunner implements Runnable {

    boolean stopRunning = false;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Camera.Parameters paramsOn = cam.getParameters();
        Camera.Parameters paramsOff = camParams;
        paramsOn.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        paramsOff.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        try {
            while (!stopRunning) {
                cam.setParameters(paramsOn);
                cam.startPreview();
                Thread.sleep(100 - freq);
                cam.setParameters(paramsOff);
                cam.startPreview();
                Thread.sleep(100 - freq);

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm gonna put it out there that this is probably a bad idea. I can see this shortening the life of the LED.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Why should that be bad??There are many Flashlight apps with a strobe effect on Google Playstore.

Comment: double check that your `sr.stopRunning = true` is working